# Fancybox width not applying

Tags: javascript, fancybox

Using the following JS the width isn't being adjusted.  It doesn't get adjusted when I use `'750'` or `'750px'`

```
$('a#city-prompt').fancybox({
    'width': 750
});
```

I've posted on the [fancybox](http://fancybox.net/api) forums about this and haven't gotten a response

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You probably have to set `autoSize` to `false`:

```
$('a#city-prompt').fancybox({
    'width': 750,
    'autoSize': false
});
```

About `width` from the [documentation](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs):

> Width for content types 'iframe' and 'swf'. Also set for inline content if 'autoDimensions' is set to 'false'

Comment: This answer is out of date. The `autoDimensions` option is not part of 2.0+ versions of Fancybox. See here: http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs - and try using `autoSize`, `autoWidth` or `autoHeight` instead.

Answer (score 7):

None of the answers here worked for me, but this did the trick:

```
$.fancybox({
    'content':$("#element").html(),
    'width':'500',
    'autoDimensions':false,
    'type':'iframe',
    'autoSize':false
});
```

The `'autoSize':false` was the missing key

Comment: What version of Fancybox are you using?  I'm wondering if they changed the name of the parameter... The one at http://fancybox.net/api uses `AutoDimensions`.  Looks like you were using `FancyBox 2` - http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs

Comment: `autoSize` did the trick for me too. Nothing else worked. Thanks

Comment: you only need `autoSize:false`, you don't even need `autoDimensions:false`. this should be the one and only accepted answer since the accepted answer is out of date and thus wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to not include the ' when writing out width in pixels. So instead of

'width' :  '100', you should have 'width' :  100,

Hope that helps...

Answer (score 1):

Try this.
You need to set `autoSize` to `false`:

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({'width':400,
                         'height':300,
                         'autoSize' : false});
```

Comment: And for percentages, use quotes like this:
'width':'80%',

Answer (score 1):

In Fancybox version 2 and above use `'autoSize':false`

[Fancybox Documentation](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/)

Answer (score 0):

Change `_get_zoom_to`  (on line 690) from

```
to.width = currentOpts.width + double_padding;
```

to

```
to.width = parseInt(currentOpts.width) + parseInt(double_padding);
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answers, to fix the height issue I changed line **998**

**from :**
`to.height = currentOpts.height + double_padding;`

**to:**
`to.height = parseInt(currentOpts.height) + parseInt(double_padding);`