# Fancybox width not applying - autoSize : false not the answer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, css

I thought I had the same problem as in these two posts:

- [Fancybox width not applying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4980930/fancybox-width-not-applying)
- [fancybox width doesn't apply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13540584/fancybox-width-doesnt-apply)

But I have been through the solutions on both and still the issue remains.

Essentially When I click on the image link the width and height properties are ignored and instead a box circa 30 x30 is shown. The video is loading and the close windows button etc all work.

I'm using I.E 8 / 9

My code is as follows:

```
<b>
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<html dir="ltr">

<head runat="server">
<META name="WebPartPageExpansion" content="full">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Untitled 1</title>
<meta name="Microsoft Theme" content="Lacquer 1011, default">

<!-- J Query Includes -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://mynationwideteam/sites/financial_performance/JavaScript/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://mynationwideteam/sites/financial_performance/JavaScript/jquery.SPServices-0.7.1a.min.js"></script>


<!-- Add fancyBox -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://mynationwideteam/sites/financial_performance/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.5" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://mynationwideteam/sites/financial_performance/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.5"></script>

<!-- Optionally add helpers - button, thumbnail and/or media -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://mynationwideteam/sites/financial_performance/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.css?v=1.0.5" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://mynationwideteam/sites/financial_performance/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js?v=1.0.5"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://mynationwideteam/sites/financial_performance/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-media.js?v=1.0.6"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://mynationwideteam/sites/financial_performance/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css?v=1.0.7" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://mynationwideteam/sites/financial_performance/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js?v=1.0.7"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".fancyvideo").fancybox({

    width : 600,
    height : 498,
    fitToView : false,
    autoSize : false,
    type : 'swf'

    });
});
</script>



</head>

<body>

<a class="fancyvideo" ID="vid1" href="http://www.youtube.com/v/92c3dX-AoXs"><img src="images/Templates/Financial_Performance/banner001.jpg" width="475" height="69" style="border-style: solid; border-width: 2px"></a>

</body>

</html>


</b>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to force the with of your content, for example you can do somethink like this (in the file that you want to include):

```
<div style="width:600px">
 //your fancy content
</div>
```

It's working for me!

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're using an older version having that property, `autoSize` doesn't exist. Try with `autoDimensions: false` and/or `autoScale: false`

Comment: Sorry should have said I've tried both of those, it was suggested on the posts above. Doesn't seem to make any difference though.